# An Example From EWD 316

Tags: algorithm

I am reading EWD 316 by Dijkstra and I got stuck with an example. On page 53 Dijkstra gives the following definition:

> Consider sequences composed of 1's, 2's and 3's which contain only pairs of different adjoining non-empty subsequences.

He calls such sequences good. The problem is to list, in alphabetical order, all good sequences up to and including the first one of length 100, given the fact that there is at least one good sequence of length 100.

First of all, I think, what Dijkstra means by "subsequence" is "substring" (I am referring to the definition on Wikipedia) but this is not the real issue. As far as I can see, the definition is symmetric in the sense that if a sequence is good, then permuting the 1's, 2's and 3's in the sequence will yield another good sequence. Because the definition does not mention a specific numeral. However, Dijkstra gives the first few good sequences (in alphabetical order) and even though, for instance, 12 is in the list the sequences 21, 13, 23, 31 and 32 are not. Also, his algorithm removes the final 3's in trial sequences.

I am pretty sure I am missing something trivial yet I could not figure out what. Also, I am not a native speaker of English so I would appreciate it even if you express the property of being good in fully formal/mathematical notation.

ps: I could not find a suitable preexisting tag.

Comment: Wouldn't "adjoining subsequence" mean "substring"?

Comment: @Dukeling. Hmm, I thought the pairs were adjoining. So my parsing was incorrect. Thanks.

Comment: Oh wait, yeah, that probably makes more sense.

Comment: @Dukeling. Back to square one. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
 contain only pairs of different adjoining non-empty subsequences
```

Means that any two substrings that are next to each other are different. My guess is that, as you suspected, *adjoining* refers to the pairs, while he is using the word *subsequences* instead of *substrings* - he definitely means substrings, otherwise `3212321` would not be good.

So starting alphabetically:

1 is good, extend with 1

11 is not good, remove trailing 3s (there are none in this case), increase last digit by 1

12 good

121 good

1211 not good

1212 not good

1213 good

...

Now, is `21` (and `13`, `23`, `31`...) in this list? `21` is clearly a "good" sequence. But `21` is alphabetically after any string starting with `1`, so if there is an infinite number of good strings starting with `1`, we will never actually get to `21`.

Imagine a simpler problem: list all natural numbers in alphabetical order.

```
1
11
111
...
```

We will never actually get to `2`. This doesn't mean it's not in the set of natural numbers, just that it is not at any finite position in the alphabetical list.

Comment: Oh, so Dijkstra could have just said square free instead of giving a long(ish) definition. Thank you very much. But in this case, how do we prove correctness of the algorithm? If we only know that there is at least one good sequence of length 100, how can we deduce that the algorithm produces a good sequence of size 100?